# Music player controlled from ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am writing automation scripts for an Android device, which communicate with the device over ADB. I would like to know if there is any music player which can play MP3 and could be controlled via ADB.

I need following controls -

- Start MP3 playback
- Stop MP3 playback
- Toggle Repeat mode

Is it possible to achieve the same via Google Music Player in Android M?

In Android M, I can play MP3 using following command -

`am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d <filename> -n com.google.android.music/.AudioPreview -f 1`

It starts the playback correctly, but not able to stop or play it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following to stop the music:

```
adb shell input keyevent 127
```